# Phonegap app stuck on splash screen for Apple reviewers

Tags: ios, phonegap-build, ipv6, appstore-approval, phonegap

I've published around a couple dozen apps to the Apple App Store over the last couple of years with no problems whatsoever. Recently, an app just got rejected due to

**"We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone and iPad running iOS 10.3.2 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
We were not able to fully load your app content after launch. 
Please see attached screenshots for details.".**

The attached screenshots were just the splash screen of the app. So it seems the app is getting stuck on the splash screen for the reviewers.

I tested the same binary (using TestFlight) on my iPhone running the same version of iOS they were using and it worked successfully. However, I was testing on an ipv4 network. I find it hard to believe that them testing on an ipv6 network would cause the PhoneGap app to hang on the splash screen. Especially considering this has never happened before.

Is it possible this was just some anomaly when Apple happened to test this app? Or has anyone else even encountered something like this where they were unable to reproduce what the reviewers were seeing?

Comment: You are supposed to test you applications on an IPv6-only network. If you do not, then you run a real risk of sending a buggy application for review. Apple provides instructions for setting up such a network.

Comment: I followed the instructions on https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html and was still unable to reproduce. It seems strange to me that testing on an ipv6 network would cause the app to crash on the splash screen. We've never faced this issue with them before, and I'd think that the app's home page would at least be launched (albeit with any data from the internet loaded onto it)

Answer (score 0):

Apple approved the app after we responded to them stating we followed https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html to no avail and that the bug was likely due to something in their testing environment.